# Ansible SSH ERROR connection in localhost

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have this error when I launch my playbook against the localhost host.

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue", "unreachable": true}
to retry, use: --limit @deploy-test-env.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

And my hosts file have this config:

```
[local]
127.0.0.1
```

What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you followed the suggestion in the error message, if so what is the verbose output?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Ansible by default tries to connect through ssh. For localhost you should set the connection to `local`.

You can define this when calling the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --connection=local
```

Define it in your playbook:

```
- hosts: local
  connection: local
```

Or, preferable, define it as a host var just for localhost/127.0.0.1. Create a file `host_vars/127.0.0.1` relative to your playbook with this content:

```
ansible_connection: local
```

You also could add it as a group var in your inventory:

```
[local]
127.0.0.1

[local:vars]
ansible_connection=local
```

or as a host var:

```
[local]
127.0.0.1   ansible_connection=local
```

See [Behavioral Parameters in docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters).

Comment: Adding it as a group var in my inventory file `/etc/ansible/hosts` worked for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It could be done way more easier.

Under the **[defaults]** section of the **ansible.cfg** file, just paste the following line:

```
transport = local
```

Comment: This is a global setting. Then you have to override it for every host other than `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is not including the localhost in the inventory and only specifying it in the hosts pattern.

i.e. hosts: localhost

This seems to imply local connection to ansible